# Cocos2d-x Delete Line (DrawNode)

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-engine

I have drawn line in cocos2d-x using this function.

```
drawNode->drawLine(point1,point2,Color4F::BLACK);
//void drawLine(const cocos2d::Vec2 &origin, const cocos2d::Vec2 &destination, const cocos2d::Color4F &color);
```

Now I want to delete this line, but I don't have hanlder of it. How can I remove this line form the drawNode.

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
drawNode->clear()
```

to clear everything drawn by the drawNode.

Use this to your advantage to call `clear()` at the beginning of each frame then drawing all lines you want to be draw.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DrawNode for each line you want to draw. Then remove the DrawNode which contains the line you want to delete from the parent.

Comment: use myDrawNode->removeFromParent()